# Filter Column in CSV and get the unique value

Tags: shell, sh

I am having three columns in a CSV: Client Name, save Set Name and Status. For some clients, we have two Status as Failed and Success both. So, I want to filter those clients only which have status as only Failed. Clients who are having two entries such as Failed and success also, I want to omit.

When I am using the listed command, it's giving me values whose status was successful also might be later on.  I want values which are only Failed. Not successful even once

```
cat "$pwd"/Daily-Failed.csv|egrep -i 'failed|Interrupted'|awk -F',' '{print $2,$3,$9}'|sort -u > "$pwd"/Final-Failed/Failed.csv
```

(edit) Or with newlines:

```
   cat "$pwd"/Daily-Failed.csv|
     egrep -i 'failed|Interrupted'|
     awk -F',' '{print $2,$3,$9}'|
     sort -u > "$pwd"/Final-Failed/Failed.csv
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xKND.png)

Please find the input and desired output.                                                                                                                                        Input                                                                                                                       Client Name, Save Set, Status
Star,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Sun,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Success
Sun,D:/,Success

Output                                                                                                                     "Client Name","Save Set",Status
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Star,D:/,Failed

Comment: Please, don't post sample (or expected output) data as an image. We can't really use it for testing or anything else, actually.

Comment: Can you give sample input here, so we can copy-paste and test?

Comment: Why is `Sun,D:/` in your output when it has two rows, one failure, one success?

Comment: Input and Output has been updated in Question

Comment: You say _am having three columns_, but your _listed command_ refers to the ninth field `$9` and nowhere to the first - how's that?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter those clients only which have status as only Failed. Clients who are having two entries such as Failed and success also, I want to omit.

I'm going to assume, looking at your sample input (Which *really* needs to be text in your question, not an image), that both the Client Name and Save Set columns matter - you have `(Star, C:/)` with both success and failure rows, and `(Star, D:/)` with just failure, and the latter shows up in your output, and that's the only way that would make sense given your stated goal. On the other hand you also have two `(Sun, D:/)` rows, one success, one failure, and that shows up in your output even though it doesn't meet your criteria any way you look at it...

Anyways, this sort of grouping and filtering of tabular data screams database, and I like to script sqlite to make it do all the work in such cases:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=Daily-Failed.csv

sqlite3 -batch -csv -header <<EOF
.import '${filename}' tbl
SELECT *
FROM tbl
GROUP BY "Client Name", "Save Set"
HAVING count(*) = 1 AND Status = 'Failed'
EOF
```

after taking the data in your image and turning it into a CSV file `Daily-Failed.csv` looking like

```
Client Name,Save Set,Status
Star,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Sun,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Success
Sun,D:/,Success
```

that script will output

```
"Client Name","Save Set",Status
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Star,D:/,Failed
```

Comment: Yes Shawn , You guess it Right. Sun should not be there and we want only Failed backups. I try your code and its giving me error                                                                                        Error: no such table: tbl
Error: incomplete SQL: SELECT *

Comment: @GURUSINGH Any errors about the import failing? You'd have to tweak it to get the right path to the CSV file of course if you didn't already.